# laravel array_map get error "array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, has-many

I'm new on laravel. Why I'm always get error:

> array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array ?

whereas I'm assigning parameter array on this method?

this is my example code :

```php
$products = Category::find(1)->products;
```

note :
1 category has many products

this is the array from query :

```
[{
   "id": "1",
   "name": "action figure",
   "created_at": "2015-11-09 05:51:25",
   "updated_at": "2015-11-09 05:51:25"
    }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "manga",
    "created_at": "2015-11-09 05:51:25",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-09 05:51:25"
}]
```

when I'm trying the following code:

```php
$results = array_map( function($prod) {
    return $prod.name;
}, $products);
```

and I get the error like below:

> "array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array"

Comment: as per error `$products` should be an array, first convert your data into an array. also check passed variable is an array or not

Comment: how to check type data on laravel @Chetan Ameta

Comment: with basic php,  you can `var_dump` the variable to analyze the variable. I think in your case `$products` is an object

Comment: basically what is your desire result? can you explain bit more in your question. What output you want?

Answer (score 9):

You should write

```php
$results = array_map(function ($prod) {
    return $prod->name;
}, $products->toArray());
```

Because `$products` is a Collection and not an array.

If you just want to have a list of product name use the `pluck` method

```php
$results = $products->pluck('name')
```

In newer version of Laravel you should use `$products->all();` instead of `toArray` because in the case of an Eloquent collection, `toArray` will try to convert your models to array too. `all` will just return an array of your models as is.

That being said, since you are on a Collection you can also use the `map` method on it like so (which is exactly the same as using `pluck` in your case)

```php
$products->map(function ($product) {
    return $product->name;
});
```

Comment: echo $products->toArray() ... return empty for me @PeterPan666

Comment: echo do not display arrays, try with `dd($products->toArray());`